# Django, Haystack: Redirect to Search results URL within a View

Tags: redirect, search, view, django-haystack

I'm using Django Haystack with Woosh as Searchengine.
Within my app i have a Searchbar which is working perfectly.

If I enter something into the search form I get the following URL something like:
/order/?q=""searchstring""

The view below gives me the correct results. From that results I build up multiple forms.
When one of these forms is submited I update the values and redirect them to to the same url which they are coming from, which makes the entire view run again (better don't ask why).
My Problem is with the searchstring see last line below.

My view includes something like this

```
    ...
    if 'q' in request.GET:
    search_form = SearchForm(request.GET)
    if search_form.is_valid():
        cd = search_form.cleaned_data
        results = SearchQuerySet().models(MyLookupModel).filter(content=cd['q']).load_all()
        results_pk = results.values_list('pk', flat=True)
    ...
    ...
    if myform_1.is_valid():
        # do something
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/order/" + ###What to put here###)
```

With out the search_form i just redirect to /order/ which makes the view run again. 
This means when ever the user searches something he gets the results, if he makes changes and submits them I want him to get the same results page shown again with updated models.

i.e. if someone searches "Harry Potter" the results are at

/order/?q=Harry Potter

So my HttpResponseRedirect should look like

```
return HttpResponseRedirect("/order/?=Harry Potter")
```

I cannot figure out how to get the searchquery or the url which called the view. When I use something like get_full_path() i only get .../order/ without the searchquery.

I really appreciate every help, thank you in advance.
Best regards,
Burnie